# Как в PHP изменить имя загружаемого файла на случайное, чтобы оно не повторялось?

Tags: php

Как в PHP изменить имя загружаемого файла на случайное, чтобы оно не повторялось?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно так: хеш (например md5) от текущего времени (`год.день.неделя.минута.секунда`).

Comment: Вероятность повтора все равно будет. Вполне может возникнуть ситуация, когда несколько пользователей одновременно заливают файлы.

Я обычно делаю md5 хеш от значения microtime() и ID пользователя, так надежней.

Comment: вероятность повтора всё равно будет, ибо такова суть мд5, я обычно храню реальные имена файлов в бд, а на диске они хранятся под именем совпадающим с `id` из той же самой базы.

Comment: @Павел Вершинин, согласен что так предлагаешь ты - надежнее.

Comment: Я, обычно, использовал что-то типа:

    $randValue = md5( rand(0,10000) . time() );
    // ...

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно рекурсивно проверять существует ли файл с таким названием и если он существует, прибавлять к имени файла какой-то бред. получится что-то в роде

```
$filename = check($name);
function check($filename){
   if( file_exists($filename) ){
      $filename = check($hash.$filename);
   }else{
      return $filename;
   }
}
```

Comment: Хоть такой алгоритм и имеет смысл, но, определенно, не для решения этой задачи, хотя, если нужно быть **абсолютно точно** уверенным в том, что повторения не будет - можно и так.

Comment: зависит от $hash. если сделать его хорошим, то количество рекурсий будет равно 0.